# Feed is empty on first start after installation

Tags: bug, ios-app

Using Version 1.1.0.117 on the iPad with iOS 7.1.2 the feed is always empty after the first start after the installation of the app. After closing and reopening the feed is populated.

Comment: Even worse my app feed has not been refreshed for weeks and after switching to a new phone it remains empty.